Bmx bike stamp on dropouts
What kind of BMX bike has an S stamped on the back drop outs? I think it is a Sunday Bike Co. bike, but I can't be for sure.

Please post a picture

Without a picture, we do not have enough information to formulate an accurate answer. Please add one, if not several pictures to your question ([edit] it to do so).

Sunday BMX has a logo with a big S.  The vertical serifs are important, but the text around the circle is optional.

Does this match your logo?   If not, please post a clear and well lit photo of your logo into your question.

Specialized stamp?
something like this?

